# How do I make a form that is already collapsed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

At the moment, I've got the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sign-up").click(function(){
        $(".collapse").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

That, when the anchor is clicked, the form will either expand or collapse. The problem I've got at the moment is that the page will load with the form expanded - I want it to be collapsed.

Many Thanks.

Comment: simply add ```.collapse``` as class to the form

Comment: Show the HTML for the .collapse element

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `style="display:none"` to the form tag assuming it is the form that is to be expanded and collapsed?